# Reset button not showing when using scrollablePlotArea

Tags: highcharts

We are using Highchart version of  Highcharts JS v8.0.4  and facing issue Reset button not showing when using scrollablePlotArea,
Is is resolved in latest version so how we can sort out it in previous version ?

Answer (score 0):

The bug is related with the fact that the button is shown, but not in the right place. As a solution, you can reposition the button in `afterShowResetZoom` event.

```
(function(H) {
    H.addEvent(H.Chart, 'afterShowResetZoom', function(e) {
        this.resetZoomButton.attr({ 
            x: this.plotSizeX,
            y: this.plotTop + 10
        });
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hnv5q2wm/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts